# Application Page textbox event for textchanged

Tags: c#, sharepoint

In SharePoint application page i have a asp:TextBox and asp:button. I have a condition when there is a Change in the TextBox text the want the Button text to be changed.

OnTextchanged Event fires only after you move the Focus out of TextBox and click somewhere.

Another Problem is if i have the onTextChanged Event the button click happens only after second click.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the onkeyup event.

```
<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onkeyup="javascript:test()"  ></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" type="button"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
         function test() {
             $("[id$=Button1]").val($("[id$=TextBox1]").val())
            
        }

    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for Reply. Is it possible to get the text from SharePoint resources.

Comment: What are the SharePoint resources?

Comment: I mean from the Hive C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\Resources